# dismissing tabbar based view controller when returning from vfr pdf controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I'm currently working on a project that is tab bar based and out of my four tabs three display just table data or images. My problem is stemming from trying to use a tab to display a PDF file with vfr. I can click the tab when the program first loads and everything appears to be working as it should. When I click done the Reader view controller is dismissed but the underlying controller is still sitting there empty. Since the view is still in place clicking back and forth through my tabs never allows vfr to reload its view since viewDidLoad is whats I'm using to call it. How do I dismiss the underlying controller? Or is there a better method to call vfr in a story board tab based app?

my controller code that calls vfr

```
@implementation testViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"emsformulary" ofType:@"pdf"];
    ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:file password:nil];

    if (document != nil) {
        ReaderViewController *readerViewController =[[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
        readerViewController.delegate = self;
        readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

        [self presentViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}


@end
```

dismissReaderViewController is called by the done button in vfr. Once called vfr pdf view is gone but a blank view remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I was calling my controller code with viewDidLoad. Once I dismissed it, it was never called again. Moving the code to viewWillAppear fixed my controller presentation issue. As for the not dismissing the underlying view, I found the method to call a view by its tabbarcontroller array index when I pressed the done button inside vfr.